# awk: Pattern substitution in one file based on input from another file

Tags: awk

I have an XML file that has a set of entries like this:

```
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo2"/>
```

What I want to do is to substitute the value field in each entry of the file by an entry of the form "nodoX", where X should be read from a second file that contains a list of numbers, e.g "file2" contains:

```
4
8
67
52
```

In that case my processed XML file should have substituted the previous entries by:

```
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo4"/>
...
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo8"/>
...
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo67"/>
...
<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo52"/>
...
```

Currently I am trying with the following awk command but it is not working:

```
awk '/"trajectory"/ {if (getline < "file2") {x=$1; sub(/"nodo2"/,"\"nodo"x"\"")}}1' $XML_INPUT_FILE > $XML_OUTPUT_FILE
```

Could someone advise the correct way to get this done in awk ?

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getline < "file2"` overwrites $0, so the `sub` command will not do what you want. Try:

```
awk '/"trajectory"/ {if (getline x < "file2") {sub(/"nodo2"/,"\"nodo"x"\"")}}1'
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getline

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do that with `awk`...

```
awk 'BEGIN { c=1 ; while ((getline line < "OTHER_NUMBERS") > 0) { a[c]=line ; c++ } }
     NR == 1 { c=1 }
     /<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo[0-9]+".>/ {
          print gensub("^(.*=.nodo)[0-9]+(.*)","\\1" a[c] "\\2","g",$0)
          c++
     }
     ! /<attr name="trajectory" value="nodo[0-9]+".>/ { print }' XMLFILE
```

Generally it reads your number files into an indexed array, then on every (matching) `trajectory`  lines prints the replacement. *Note* that it can fail you, if the number of lines in the numbers file is less than the number of `nodo` lines...

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 awk 'FNR==NR{n[++i]=$1;next};/"trajectory"/{sub(/[0-9]+/,n[++j],$3)}1' file2 XML
```

Answer (score 0):

solution below

```
awk '
BEGIN{i = 0; while(getline num < "file2"){a[i] = num;i++}}
/"trajectory"/{sub(/nodo2/,"node"a[NR-1], $0);print $0}' file1
```